# How to access to the browser without a button? (ionic 3)

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, browser

I want to use "Themeable Browser", I have a button and when I click on it, the browser opens.

How to remove the button, and have the browser directly on my page?

### JS

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private themeableBrowser: ThemeableBrowser) { }

openBrowser() {
    const options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
        toolbar: {
            height: 44,
            color: '#3573bbff'
        },
        title: {
            color: '#ffffffff',
            showPageTitle: true,
            staticText: 'Academy Browser'
        },
        backButton: {
            wwwImage: 'assets/img/back.png',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'backPressed'
        },
        forwardButton: {
            wwwImage: 'assets/img/forward.png',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'forwardPressed'
        },
        closeButton: {
            wwwImage: 'assets/img/close.png',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'closePressed'
        },
    };

    const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.themeableBrowser.create('https://twitter.com/', '_blank', options);

    browser.on('closePressed').subscribe(data => {
        browser.close();
    })
}
```

### HTML

```
<button ion-button full (click)="openBrowser()">Open Browser</button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing in your typescript

> openBrowser()

with

> ionViewDidEnter()

ionViewDidEnter() runs when you enter the page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

Comment: It works my friend but, why my browser doesn't show up in my application?? When I go to my page, I leave the application and it's the google chrome browser that opens.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what happens when you enter the page? Also, your imports on your typescript file. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you're running the application on the browser instead of running it on a mobile device. Try running it on android and see what happens.

Comment: I understand. But, how could I work on my application if I can't see its evolution in a preview lol? Is there a solution for this? :/

Comment: You will have to run an emulator to test this out or run it on an android device. You are creating a cordova application so what matters is whether or not it will work in the device, not on the browser. By the way, if my solution solved your question please select it as the correct answer. Thanks!